# Robustness Check 50/50 sample split

Tags: r, dataframe, addition

Hi guys I need to do a robustness check with my dataframe consisting of 811777 rows and 15 columns. To do the 50/50 sample split I want to add a column with the numbers 1 and 0 alternately. In the end I want to create one dataframe with only the rows that have a "0" in the last column and the other dataframe should consist of the rows that had a "1" in the last column.

To add the column into my dataframe I have the code:

```
mydata$rec <- 1
```

But with this code I only get "1" in my new column but I want 1 and 0 alternately in the last column. Does somebody know how I can do it?

Thanks for ur help! :)

Comment: You could use `mydata$red <- rep(1:0, nrow(mydate)/2)`

Comment: Thank u for ur answer but with this code ```wsl_all$rec <- rec(1:0, nrow(wsl_all)/2)``` I get the following error message: "Error in UseMethod("transmute") : 
  no applicable method for 'transmute' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: Try `wsl_all$rec <- 1L; wsl_all$rec[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- 0L`. And check with `mean(wsl_all$rec)`, it should be very close to 0.5. (The trick is that the logical index recycles to the full length of the vector `rec`.)

Comment: In @Kat's comment the function is `rep`, you are using `rec`, hence the error.

Comment: The `nrow()/2` trick doesn't work on odd lengthed data. `wsl_all$rec<-rep_len(0:1, nrow(wsl_all))`

Comment: Good point @M.Viking

Comment: Not a better answer but a different one: `mydata$rec <- `+`(1:nrow(mydata) %% 2 != 0)`. Note that there should be back ticks around the "+"